# Sort multidimensional array by two strings

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array that I need to have sorted by name([0]) and platform ([2])

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Assassins Creed: Syndicate
        [1] => 199
        [2] => PC
        [3] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Assassins Creed: Syndicate
        [1] => 199
        [2] => XONE
        [3] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Assassins Creed: Syndicate
        [1] => 199
        [2] => PC
        [3] => 1
    )
)
```

I already have usort function, that sorts array by name, but I don't know how to sort it also by platform (so that xbox would be on the last position).

```
function sort_by_name($a, $b)   {
if ($a == $b)
return 0;
return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I would like to get array sorted like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => Assassins Creed: Syndicate
    [1] => 199
    [2] => PC
    [3] => 1
)
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => Assassins Creed: Syndicate
    [1] => 199
    [2] => PC
    [3] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
(
    [0] => Assassins Creed: Syndicate
    [1] => 199
    [2] => XONE
    [3] => 1
)
)
```

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: What is your expected output over here post it down too.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. Basicaly I need my function to sort it by alphabet by string in [0] and also by alphabet in [2].

Comment: You use database? mysql or postgre

Comment: I use mysql, but i need to sort array above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `usort` function like as

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
    $c = strcmp($a[0],$b[0]);
    $c .= strcmp($a[2],$b[2]);
    return $c;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array_multisort()

In short you build two arrays from the values you want to sort by and pass them into array_multi_sort()

Comment: It is not possible to use usort?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want it sorted first by title and then by platform? (Your example has all the same titles so that's not clear)

Logically, this is no different from sorting it by one long phrase containing the title and platform, so you should be able to sort it by the concatenation of them.

```
function sort_by_name($a, $b)   {
   if ($a == $b)
      return 0;
   return (($a[0] . $a[2]) < ($b[0] . $b[2])) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Of course, this relies on the title being spelled exactly the same in each instance (incl. spaces, capitalisation etc.) but you'd have that with any sort

Answer (score 0):

You need [array_multisort](http://php.net/array_multisort)

```
$sort = array();
foreach($YOUR_ARRAY as $k=>$v) {
    $sort[0][$k] = $v[0];
    $sort[2][$k] = $v[2];
}



array_multisort($sort['0'], SORT_DESC, $sort[2], SORT_ASC, $YOUR_ARRAY);
```